# Code outputs both negative and non-negative 0 to be true

Tags: javascript, html, math

Here are two cases:

```
console.log(Math.abs(-16) % 2 === 0) //true
console.log(Math.abs(-16) % 2 === -0) //true
```

In the second case, isn't `Math.abs()` supposed to change -16 into 16, therefore making it return `false` because `16 % 2 !== -0`?
Also how can i solve it so that the second case (`console.log(Math.abs(-16) % 2 === -0)`) doesn't return `true`, instead, `false`

Comment: You can't do this because `-0 === 0`

Comment: console.log(0 === -0) // output -> true.

Answer (score 1):

You need `Object.is` if you want to tell the difference between positive and negative zeroes:

```js
console.log(Object.is(-16 % 2, +0)) // false
console.log(Object.is(-16 % 2, -0)) // true
```